# Getting access to EKCalendar

Tags: swift, calendar

In my app, I have a switch that allows the user to put certain events in their agenda. I handle that as such:

```
@IBAction func putInAgenda(_ sender: UISwitch) {
        let store = manager.store
        if (sender.isOn){
            store.requestAccess(to: EKEntityType.event, completion: {
                (accessGranted: Bool, error: Error?) in
                if accessGranted == true {
                    self.eventsHandler.importEventsInAgenda(id)
                } else {
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        sender.isOn = false
                    }
                }
            })
        } else {
            //
        }

        shared?.set(sender.isOn, forKey: "putInAgenda")
        shared?.synchronize()
    }
```

However, against my expectation, "store.requestAccess" not only requests, but also SETS.

As a result, when the user CANCELS the dialog, the switch switches back (expected) but any consecutive attempt to switch the switch to the ON position is honored with an OFF position, without a new dialog.

What should I do?

Comment: Unrelated but the call to `synchronize` is obsolete. See its documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A privacy request is only ever asked once. If you detect that it is currently denied, you could either update the UI or prompt the user to go to Settings and turn it on. You can use `UIApplication openSettingsURLString` and `UIApplication openURL` to take the user to your app's settings page in the Settings app.